# JavaFX TableView, Labels and Buttons selection is not working and looks and the table looks disabled

Tags: button, javafx, label, tableview, javafx-8

This is my first question in this great community. I started a Java FX tutorial on this blog http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ . But I am using IntelliJ IDEA instead of Eclipse. The program compiles successfully but both the TableView in the left and the labels in the right look like they are disabled ( the font color is gray and not black and the table can not be highlighted on mouse hover or click ). So my question is : Why can not I select the Table view ?

[TableView, Labels and Buttons looks disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrPLN.png)

```
package com.melkojji.controller;

import com.melkojji.model.Person;
import com.melkojji.view.PersonOverviewController;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;
    private ObservableList<Person> personData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public Main() {
        this.personData.add(new Person("Mustapha", "HUSAIN"));
        this.personData.add(new Person("Mustapha", "EL KOJJI"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("AdressApp");
        this.primaryStage.setMinWidth(615);
        this.primaryStage.setMinHeight(365);
        initRootLayout();
        showPersonOverview();
    }

    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("../view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void showPersonOverview() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("../view/PersonOverview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);
            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            PersonOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMain(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public ObservableList<Person> getPersonData() {
        return personData;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.melkojji.view;

import com.melkojji.controller.Main;
import com.melkojji.model.Person;
import com.melkojji.util.DateUtil;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

/**
 * Created by melkojji on 1/14/2017.
 */
public class PersonOverviewController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> personTableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> personFirstNameTableColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> personLastNameTableColumn;
    @FXML
    private Label firstNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label lastNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label streetLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label postalCodeLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label cityLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label birthdayLabel;
    // Reference to the main application.
    private Main main;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
     */
    public PersonOverviewController() {
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        // Initialize the person table with the two columns.
        this.personFirstNameTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        this.personLastNameTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
        // Clear person details.
        showPersonDetails(null);
        // Listen for selection changes and show the person details when changed.
        personTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showPersonDetails(newValue)));
    }

    /**
     * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     *
     * @param main
     */
    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
        // Add observable list data to the table.
        this.personTableView.setItems(main.getPersonData());
    }

    /**
     * Fills all text fields to show details about the person.
     * If the specified person is null, all text fields are cleared.
     *
     * @param person the person or null
     */
    public void showPersonDetails(Person person) {
        if (person != null) {
            // Fill the labels with info from the person object.
            firstNameLabel.setText(person.getFirstName());
            lastNameLabel.setText(person.getLastName());
            streetLabel.setText(person.getStreet());
            postalCodeLabel.setText(Integer.toString(person.getPostalCode()));
            cityLabel.setText(person.getCity());
            birthdayLabel.setText(DateUtil.format(person.getBirthday()));
            // birthdayLabel.setText(...);
        } else {
            // Person is null, remove all the text.
            firstNameLabel.setText("");
            lastNameLabel.setText("");
            streetLabel.setText("");
            postalCodeLabel.setText("");
            cityLabel.setText("");
            birthdayLabel.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="325.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane disable="true" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.melkojji.view.PersonOverviewController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="personTableView" editable="true" onSort="#initialize" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="175.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="personFirstNameTableColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="First name" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="personLastNameTableColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Last name" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
               </children></AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Person details :" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0" />
                  <GridPane AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="First name" />
                        <Label text="Last name" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="Street" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="City" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Label text="Postal code" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                        <Label text="Birthday" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                        <Label fx:id="firstNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <Label fx:id="lastNameLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label fx:id="streetLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label fx:id="cityLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Label fx:id="postalCodeLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                        <Label fx:id="birthdayLabel" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
                  <ButtonBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                    <buttons>
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                    </buttons>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets right="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </ButtonBar>
               </children></AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`disable` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty) will disable a node *and all child nodes* when set. So, because you have

```
<AnchorPane disable="true" ..>
```

the anchor pane and all its subnodes, including the table, are disabled.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It is working now using your solution.